# What Content-Type value should I send for my XML sitemap?

Tags: xml, mime-types, sitemap, xml-sitemap

I thought I should send "text/xml", but then I read that I should send "application/xml". Does it matter? Can someone explain the difference?

Answer (score 180, accepted):

The [difference between *text/xml* and *application/xml*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3023#section-3) is the default character encoding if the *charset* parameter is omitted:

> Text/xml and application/xml behave differently when the charset
> parameter is not explicitly specified.  If the default charset (i.e.,
> US-ASCII) for text/xml is inconvenient for some reason (e.g., bad web
> servers), application/xml provides an alternative (see "Optional
> parameters" of application/xml registration in Section 3.2).

For [*text/xml*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3023#section-3.1):

> Conformant with [RFC2046], if a text/xml entity is received with
> the charset parameter omitted, MIME processors and XML processors
> MUST use the default charset value of "us-ascii"[ASCII].  In cases
> where the XML MIME entity is transmitted via HTTP, the default
> charset value is still "us-ascii".

For [*application/xml*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3023#section-3.2):

> If an application/xml entity is received where the charset
> parameter is omitted, no information is being provided about the
> charset by the MIME Content-Type header.  Conforming XML
> processors MUST follow the requirements in section 4.3.3 of [XML]
> that directly address this contingency.  However, MIME processors
> that are not XML processors SHOULD NOT assume a default charset if
> the charset parameter is omitted from an application/xml entity.

So if the *charset* parameter is omitted, the character encoding of *text/xml* is US-ASCII while with *application/xml* the character encoding can be specified in the document itself.

Now a rule of thumb on the internet is: “Be strict with the output but be tolerant with the input.” That means make sure to meet the standards as much as possible when delivering data over the internet. But build in some mechanisms to overlook faults or to guess when receiving and interpreting data over the internet.

So in your case just pick one of the two types (I recommend *application/xml*) and make sure to specify the used character encoding properly (I recommend to use the respective default character encoding to play safe, so in case of *application/xml* use UTF-8 or UTF-16).

Answer (score 27):

As a rule of thumb, the safest bet towards making your document be treated properly by all web servers, proxies, and client browsers, is probably the following:

1. Use the application/xml content type
2. Include a character encoding in the content type, probably UTF-8
3. Include a matching character encoding in the encoding attribute of the XML document itself.

In terms of the [RFC 3023](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3023) spec, which some browsers fail to implement properly, the  major difference in the content types is in how clients are supposed to treat the character encoding, as follows:

For application/xml, application/xml-dtd, application/xml-external-parsed-entity, or any one of the subtypes of application/xml such as application/atom+xml, application/rss+xml or application/rdf+xml, the character encoding is determined in this order:

1. the encoding given in the charset parameter of the Content-Type HTTP header
2. the encoding given in the encoding attribute of the XML declaration within the document,
3. utf-8.

For text/xml, text/xml-external-parsed-entity, or a subtype like text/foo+xml, the encoding attribute of the XML declaration within the document is ignored, and the character encoding is:

1. the encoding given in the charset parameter of the Content-Type HTTP header, or
2. us-ascii.

Most parsers don't implement the spec; they ignore the HTTP Context-Type and just use the encoding in the document. With so many ill-formed documents out there, that's unlikely to change any time soon.

Answer (score 9):

both are fine.

text/xxx means that in case the program does not understand xxx it makes sense to show the file to the user as plain text. application/xxx means that it is pointless to show it.

Please note that those content-types were originally defined for E-Mail attachment before they got later used in Web world.

Answer (score 7):

text/xml is for documents that would be meaningful to a human if presented as text without further processing, application/xml is for everything else

> Every XML entity is suitable for use with the application/xml media
>     type without modification.  But this does not exploit the fact that
>     XML can be treated as plain text in many cases.  MIME user agents
>     (and web user agents) that do not have explicit support for
>     application/xml will treat it as application/octet-stream, for
>     example, by offering to save it to a file.
>
> To indicate that an XML entity should be treated as plain text by
>     default, use the text/xml media type.  This restricts the encoding
>     used in the XML entity to those that are compatible with the
>     requirements for text media types as described in [RFC-2045] and
>     [RFC-2046], e.g., UTF-8, but not UTF-16 (except for HTTP).

— http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2376.txt

Comment: Still, it's funny that the preferred HTML MIME type is `text/html` and the preferred XHTML MIME type is `application/xhtml+xml`.

Comment: Not really. `text/html` has been around for a very long time, and it was a bit late to change it.

Answer (score 3):

Other answers here address the general question of what the proper `Content-Type` for an XML response is, and conclude (as with [What's the difference between text/xml vs application/xml for webservice response](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4832357/1709587)) that both `text/xml` and `application/xml` are permissible. However, none address whether there are any rules specific to *sitemaps*.

Answer: there aren't. The sitemap spec is https://www.sitemaps.org, and using Google `site:` searches you can confirm that it does not contain the words or phrases *mime*, *mimetype*, *content-type*, *application/xml*, or *text/xml* anywhere. In other words, it is entirely silent on the topic of what `Content-Type` should be used for serving sitemaps.

In the absence of any commentary in the sitemap spec directly addressing this question, we can safely assume that the same rules apply as when choosing the `Content-Type` of any other XML document - i.e. that it may be either `text/xml` or `application/xml`.