# Which content type should i use for xml sitemap? And which one for rss and atom feed?

Tags: rss, content-type, sitemap, atom-feed

Should i use `application/xml` or `text/xml` or some other `content-type`? I'm trying to figure out which one must be for `rss and atom feed` and which one for a `xml sitemap`. I have googled this already but some sites have one and others another.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What Content-Type value should I send for my XML sitemap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3272534/what-content-type-value-should-i-send-for-my-xml-sitemap)

Answer (score 0):

You should consult the respective specifications.

For [Atom](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4287#section-2): `application/atom+xml`

For non-specific XML documents, e.g. a sitemap: `application/xml` (see [What Content-Type value should I send for my XML sitemap?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3272534/1591669))

RSS might depend on the version you use.