# How to send an XML as response to a HTTP post request from a JSP

Tags: java, xml, jsp, servlets

I need to create a jsp that returns (a small) xml as response to a HTTP POST request. I tried googling and found some pages in SO that accomplish this using servlets as follows:

```
response.setContentType("text/xml");
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
```

and then writing the xml through the `out` object. I couldn't find a way to do the same with JSP. Any pointers on how to do that in JSP will be really helpful.

Comment: Don't do it in a JSP.

Comment: A JSP is essentially meant to be a view.  If you're sending XML as the response, just set the ContentType to "text/xml" as above and print the XML.  You shouldn't need a JSP to do that.

Comment: Many recommend using application/xml as the content-type, not text/xml. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3272534/what-content-type-value-should-i-send-for-my-xml-sitemap

Answer (score 2):

This is very easy. And I'm mentioning the sacrosanct "you should never use Java code in a JSP" right here, so no need to downvote this answer for showing how to do what you believe should not be done.

```
 <%
 response.setContentType("text/xml");
 String somedata = "whatever";
 out.print("\n<root>");
 out.print("\n   <othertag>" + somedata + "</othertag>");
 out.print("\n</root>");
 %>
```

Or:

```
 <%     
 response.setContentType("text/xml"); 
 String somedata = "whatever";
 %>
 <root>
   <othertag><%=somedata%></othertag>
 </root>
```