# create and download xml with button and domdocument

Tags: php, xml, domdocument

well what i wnat to do is create a xml file and download it, if it is possible not saving in the server.

what i have so far is creating the xml with DOMDocument and store it in the server

```
<?php
$domTree = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$rootXML = $domTree->createElement( 'XML' );
$rootXML = $domTree->appendChild($rootXML);

$personalData = $domTree->createElement( 'PERSONAL' );
$personalData = $rootXML->appendChild($personalData);
$personalData ->nodeValue = "Alan";
$domTree->save('MyXmlFile.xml');
?>
```

i know i supposed to use something like this

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/xml');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="text.xml"');

echo $xml_contents;
?>
```

but using DOMDocument im lost in hwo using it, THANKS IN ADVANCE!

Comment: If you put those header calls in your document then `echo $domTree->saveXML();` it should do the trick

Comment: GREAT!!!! thanks worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

To output to the *standard output* - that is what PHP sends to the browser - you can make use of the [PHP output stream](http://php.net/wrappers.php.php):

```
header('Content-type: text/xml');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="text.xml"');
$domTree->save('php://stdout');
```

This principle work with (nearly) anything in PHP that expects a filename which is a pretty nice feature. Compare for example with my answer to [*phpexcel to download*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8566252/367456).

It is merely the same as when you would do:

```
echo $domTree->saveXML();
```

as `echo` as well "prints" to the standard output. But for larger data, the concept of a stream is preferable.

If you want to learn more about standard output, Wikipedia has an overview about these so called standard streams:

- [Standard streams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams)

For the correct XML content-type, this depends a bit what you do, I suggest taking a look into if you like to learn a bit more:

- [What Content-Type value should I send for my XML sitemap?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3272534/367456)