# from url to file using java

Tags: java, xml, json

I am trying to download data from an URL to a file in xml form, but I am getting it in json instead. My code:

```
URL url1 = new URL("http://api.eancdn.com/ean-services/rs/hotel/v3/list?cid=55505&minorRev=28"
                            +"&apiKey=m9sur8fsbdemjck7y9yydmfx&locale=en_EN&currencyCode=USD&latitude=" +latitudes[i1]+"&longitude=" + longitudes[i1]);
ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(url1.getInputStream());
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(hotel);
fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
```

How can I get it in xml format ?

Comment: What does your API require in order to respond with XML? That's not something we can know.

Comment: So? Just parse it as JSON then.

Answer (score 0):

The answer completely depends on your API. Is it even possible for it to respond with XML?

Typically, you'll want to provide an [`Accept`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) header with the appropriate content type. In this case, that is [`application/xml`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3272534/what-content-type-value-should-i-send-for-my-xml-sitemap). This header will indicate to the server that the client only wants response bodies of that content type.

Setting a request header depends on the HTTP client. Here you are just using the `URL` type. [Get an `HttpURLConnection` from it and set its request property with `setRequestProperty`.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/how-to-use-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests)

Comment: what should i put as key and value on the setRequestProperty ?

Comment: @alex The accept header name and value. Again, maybe your service does things diiferently.