# requests <Response [500]>

Tags: xml, python-requests

I am looking to use the requests class to get data from the web and then post changes to the namespace XML and load back up.

I am able to log-in and get data using requests via:

```
data_req = requests.get(proj_data_url, headers=headers, auth=(_user, _pw))
```

where headers is `{'X-ApiKey': A-ApiKey, 'Authorization': Authorization}`

`data_req` is a `<Response [200]>`

I then use

```
data_tree = xml.etree.ElementTree.fromstring(data_req.content)
```

to convert into the and successfully make changes to the `data_tree`

I then use

```
data_set = xml.etree.ElementTree.tostring(data_tree)
```

to convert back to a string.

I then attempt to post the changes back up via:

```
_response = requests.post(proj_data_url, data=data_set, headers=headers, auth=(_user, _pw))
```

but receive `_response = <Response [500]>`, which is apparently a server error.

Can anyone help?

Comment: A quick follow-up question:

Comment: the fromstring() returns an Element instance. Does the tostring() create the proper string representation of the XML for the Element to be posted back up? This doesn't need to be a string representation of an XML Tree instance does it?

Answer (score 0):

So without knowing the Server or the XML you're posting, there's no way anyone can help with a server error.

The 500 means that the application that you're speaking to, did not handle something being wrong internally. For example, if the application is written in Python then the 500 could be the result of an unhandled exception in the code.

Without more details, you should instead endeavor to contact the site administrators for help. They can inspect their logs, fix their application, and tell you how to properly send a request to their service.

One thing you might try doing, is setting the content-type for your POST request. You can do this by updating `headers` like so

```
headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/xml'  # or 'application/xml'
```

(See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3272572/1953283) to determine which you should send.)

Comment: When running your suggestion, I get a 400 response for either. I am going to contact the site administrators tomorrow, and will follow up.

headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/xml' #or 'application/xml'
_response = requests.post(proj_data_url, data=data_set, headers=headers, auth=(_user, _pw))

Comment: I have confirmed that the proper 'Content-Type' is being posted as 'application/xml' and the tostring() encoding is correct as 'UTF-8'.

Comment: So a 400 is better than a 500, if only because it means whatever you're doing is firmly wrong and it's not causing the server to blow up. Without more details though, I can't help you figure out *what* is wrong about your request, so you should continue to talk to the site administrators.