# XML Validation error : EntityRef: expecting ';'

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I am using PHP's SimpleXML to process an XML file, and get this error:

```
Message: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 9: parser error : EntityRef: expecting ';'
```

A quick Google search reveals that this is generally caused by an un-escaped & - there's a dozen questions with that answer here on Stack Overflow.  However, here's line 9 of the file:

```
<p>In-kingdom commentary on the following items can be found on the November LoP. https://oscar.sca.org/kingdom/kingloi.php?kingdom=9&amp;loi=4191</p>
```

As you can see, the & is escaped.  A text search on the file reveals no other instances of &.

What am I missing?

Please note:  I have no ability to edit the XML file - I must take it as it comes and only fix things in my code.  I currently open the XML with the following code:

```
    $rawstring = file_get_contents($filename);
    $safestring = html_entity_decode($rawstring, 0, 'ISO-8859-1');
    $xmlstring = simplexml_load_string($safestring);
```

(the html_entity_decode is necessary as the file uses Latin-1 encoding and simplexml expects UTF-8)

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`html_entity_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/function.html-entity-decode.php) is not intended for what you appear to think it is intended for and is actually exactly what is causing your problem. As the name suggests: it decodes html entities, like `&amp;`, into their actual representation; in the case of `&amp;` => `&`.

If you want to convert the character encoding of the original `$rawstring` to `ISO-8859-1` or `UTF-8` you should use something like [`iconv()`](http://php.net/manual/function.iconv.php) or [`mb_convert_encoding()`](http://php.net/manual/function.mb-convert-encoding.php).

Here's an example that *should* work:

```
$rawstring = file_get_contents($filename);
$safestring = mb_convert_encoding($rawstring, 'ISO-8859-1' /*, $optionalOriginalEncoding */);
$xmlstring = simplexml_load_string($safestring);
```

<sup>See the [list of supported encodings](http://php.net/manual/mbstring.supported-encodings.php), as well.</sup>

---

However, since the original `$rawstring` is `Latin-1`, conversion to `ISO-8859-1` is pointless, since [`Latin-1` *is* `ISO-8859-1`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO-8859-1). You *may* need to convert to `UTF-8`, but I'm fairly certain that that's not even necessary either.

Comment: The problem caused by html_entity_decode() certainly makes sense - hadn't thought of that.

Unfortunately, mb_convert_encoding doesn't work right either.  I used the line:

 $safestring = mb_convert_encoding($rawstring, 'UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1');

To convert from Latin-1 (ISO-8859-1) to UTF-8, and it did not process special characters correctly.  For example, 'Æ' and 'ö' in the original both became 'Ã' in the output.  This XML set uses a lot of foreign characters, preserving them is important.

Comment: How are you viewing the output? If you are viewing the output in a browser, make sure the correct HTTP `Content-Type` header is set, for instance as: `Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8`. Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3272534) for more options.

Comment: So here's the weird thing.  Using this code:

`$rawstring = file_get_contents($filename);
        $safestring = mb_convert_encoding($rawstring, 'UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1');
        $xmlstring = simplexml_load_string($safestring);`
and then do `echo xmlstring->asXML();` everything looks good.  But then  I go through that string.  I have some code that goes through the XML to pull out the relevant items.  Specifically I have the following nested items (skipping irrelevant stuff):

Comment: `foreach ($xmlstring->xpath('//item') as $item) {`
`$sectionxml = simplexml_load_string($item->discussion->{'name-discussion'}->asXML());`
`$namediscussion = '';`
`foreach($sectionxml->xpath('//p') as $p) {`
`$namediscussion = $namediscussion . strip_tags($p->asXML()) . '</br>'; }}}`

and then `echo $namediscussion`, the foreign characters are garbled.

Comment: This is despite having content-type set.